Strange encoding when forwarding plain text email within the organisation
I have an issue,
When I get a plain text format email (or sending one to myself) and then forwarding it within my organisation. Strange things happens with Swedish Characters ÅÖÄ and special characthers like @£$€.
Swedish characters ÅÄÖ will become for example = +AOUA5AD2- +AEAAowAkIKwAew-
First hand plain text email nothing happends. But when i send/forward an email that i already got that is in plain text format the above happens.
I have standard html/utf8 setting for my outlook and this doesnt happend to just me.

Ok, so this seems to be what we experienced with plain text emails. When you receive email encoded in plain text and you reply that email gets converted to UTF7 charset. Seems to be related to application of labeling policy. We fixed this in our tenant with the help of MS support.
And it happens when you reply from Outlook but not from Outlook on the web. In OWA this did not happen for us.

I can't comment due to not being here long enough, so let's hope this is an answer and it's correct.
In the plain-text part of your multipart mime email there is probably a sub-heading that says charset. The mail sent to you is going to be in a different char set from the one you use e.g. it'll be ISO-8859 and you are sending in UTF8. This screws up certain chars esp. things like symbols, diacritics etc.
For example, I've just looked at an incoming mail and it has a header
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"


Thanks for answering.
How do i check header if it is in plain text? I cant view source when i right click in email.

@As4rikru In MS Outlook try right-clicking the email from the list and choosing 'view source'. Additionally, I am on a Mac and there's an option to reply and forward in the original format. Go to settings and find the tickbox under 'Composing' - that might solve your problem. Not sure.

I cant view source when its a plain text email.
I tried to send it to my gmail account and there i could look at the original source.
But whats the solution? We cant control each email if it is plain text that we get.
When we get a plain text email and we forward it within the organisation its gets UTF7 format.
And most of the cases we can see the email correctly (in outlook). But when its stored and handled by Biztalk it gets the wrong encoding and gets unreadable.
This is Sweden/Finland/Denmark, we have some special characters..but it also happends to @€$£$

@As4rikru Sorry, I have no idea about Biztalk. I use Outlook only because I am forced to use it. The reason I knew about the charset was because I had a similar problem handling emails on AWS and I had to write a Python script to handle it. If you can't select 'reply and forward in same format' I am not sure what options you have. ASCII certainly won't work. I wish everyone would just use UTF8, but that's easy to say when you speak only English :) . Do you use Windows? Could you script something in VB macros?

I have done the below test:
Create a new email > change it format to plaint text > type the "Test+AOUA5AD2- +AEAAowAkIKwAew-" field in the email body > send it to myself > forward the sent email to other account.
The email body is shown as "Test+AOUA5AD2- +AEAAowAkIKwAew-", which doesn't reproduce your issue. Is there any difference between my test and your steps? If not, what's the version of your Outlook? (File>Office account>About Outlook)
In order to further confirm if the issue is related to your Outlook desktop client, please log in to your web mail and do the same test to check if the issue persists.

There is no problem to view the email in outlook or any other account. But when we send the mail to a system that dont understand ut7 the problems occur.
Re-sending an a plain text email within the organisation gets the issue.
